# How to output time sensitive data from Node.js with too much going on in the thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, robotics

I've been working on controlling robots in Node.js for a few years now, and one big one I've been futzing with for a while is [cncserver](https://github.com/techninja/cncserver), which acts as a ReSTful service to abstract CNC drawing for client applications.

The nitty gritty here is that I need to be able to queue thousands of serial commands telling a motor to move for a given number of milliseconds, and send them out to the robot with millisecond accuracy. Anything that slows that down means the last command doesn't execute flushly with the next, and that's bad robot performance/jitter. They can be added to the queue at any speed, as long as it's faster than their read out to the robot, there's no issue.

I've been using a low level cheesy native implementation with a simple array, where items are popped off the end when sent, a simple timeout runs for the required duration, and then it's repeated. This works seamlessly and very well for even > 100k commands, but using express to handle the adding of these commands via the restful service at ~200/sec kills the thread and command execution takes a back seat.

I've been considering using streams, but they seem a little wrong as the serial port piece would/could be a very slow consumer, also there's no guarantee whatever method I used to ensure timing in the stream wouldn't get messed up by a busy thread.

What time sensitive options are there? Could I run a second process/thread/worker that simply manages CRUD for the buffer and timing? Maybe a callback queue module?

Comment: If you have multiple cpus, then forking a second process should help. Does it have to be a RESTful solution with express? Could it be implemented with websockets?

Comment: A forked process certainly wouldn't need to communicate with the main process ReSTfully, but the main server application would with clients. I've already built in a websocket component for streaming updates about buffer and execution state (along with realtime robot position), but streaming large amounts of data through this has also led to execution slowdowns. A new process managed via IPC may be the only way to ensure stability and time sensitivity in the "single thread" world of node :/